# Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed. See the server log for details. BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Tags: tomcat, netbeans

At first, I got  Deployment error: Starting of Tomcat failed, port 8080 is already in use.See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Then after updating port 8089 (start) and 8079(shut). It stoped to say port used but still it fail to start tomcat.

**Apache Tomcat or TomEE log**

```
    Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.0\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
ERROR: transport error 202: failed to create shared memory listener: Cannot create a file when that file already exists
ERROR: JDWP Transport dt_shmem failed to initialize, TRANSPORT_INIT(510)
JDWP exit error AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197): No transports initialized [debugInit.c:750]
FATAL ERROR in native method: JDWP No transports initialized, jvmtiError=AGENT_ERROR_TRANSPORT_INIT(197)
```

What i have already done:

- added manager script role as : `<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,role1,manager-script,manager-gui,admin"/>`
- changed to "no proxy"
- edited catalania.bat(removed " ")
  `:noJuliConfig
  set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_CONFIG%
  :noJuliManager
  set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% %LOGGING_MANAGER%`
- Working as administrator. Even though given full control to everyother a/c.

Comment: Try setting port number to `8084`

Comment: already tried does not work